# How run 2 and more nodes on same selenium hub programmatically(without console)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I can run 1 node on selenium grid hub.

Here is snippet of my code.

```
        GridHubConfiguration config = new GridHubConfiguration()
        config.setHost("localhost")
        config.setTimeout(60000000)
        Hub hub = new Hub(config)
        hub.start()

        RegistrationRequest req = new RegistrationRequest()
        req.setRole(GridRole.NODE)


        Map<String, Object> nodeConfiguration = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.PROXY_CLASS, "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy")
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.MAX_SESSION, 25)
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.PORT, 5555)
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.HOST, hub.getHost())
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.AUTO_REGISTER, true)
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.REGISTER_CYCLE, 5000)
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.HUB_HOST, hub.getHost())
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.HUB_PORT, hub.getPort())
        URL remoteURL = new URL("http://" + hub.getHost() + ":" + 5555)
        nodeConfiguration.put(RegistrationRequest.REMOTE_HOST, remoteURL)

        req.setConfiguration(nodeConfiguration)

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName","chrome")
        capabilities.setCapability("maxInstances",25)
        capabilities.setCapability("seleniumProtocol","Selenium")

        req.setCapabilities([capabilities]);

        SelfRegisteringRemote remote = new SelfRegisteringRemote(req)
        remote.startRemoteServer()
        remote.startRegistrationProcess()
```

I have 3 problems..

1. As you can see I set MAX_SESSION and maxInstances to 25, although I can't run more than 10 Chrome driver Instances, maybe I did something wrong or maybe it is a bug?
2. How run 2 and more nodes on same selenium hub programmatically(without console) ?
3. How run web driver in headless mode? There is a very usefull link 
   [Headless tests with Firefox and Chrome WebDriver](http://www.seleniumtests.com/2012/04/headless-tests-with-firefox-webdriver.html), but I couldn't find out how do it for Selenium grid.

I am using **selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar**

Comment: have it working by now?

Comment: You're setting Max Session, but there is also a setting called Max Instances. Please read here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2
Thier documentation will tell you the difference between instances and session.